# How to fix position image on another image

Tags: html, css

I have the following [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2djy5g-7svg91?file=index.js) (also pasted below), where I want to make a layout of two columns. In the first one I am putting two images, and in the second displaying some text.

In the first column, I want to have the first image with `width:70%` and the second one with `position:absolute` on it. The final result should be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29PYr.png)

As you see the second image partially located in first one in every screens above to `768px`.

I can partially locate second image on first one, but that is not dynamic, if you change screen dimensions you can see how that collapse.

But no matter how hard I try, I can not achieve this result.

```css
.checkoutWrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.coverIMGLast {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100vh;
}

/* this .phone class should be dynamically  located partially on first image */
.phone {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90%;
  top: 5%;
  bottom: 5%;
  margin-left: 18%;
}

.CheckoutProcess {
  padding: 5.8rem 6.4rem;
}

.someContent {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* removing for demo purposes
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .checkoutWrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
  }
  img {
    display: none;
  }
  .CheckoutProcess {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="checkoutWrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="coverIMGLast" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/ff0000" class="phone" />

  <div class="CheckoutProcess">
    <Content />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The demo above basically looks like your image. In what way is it wrong? Please revise to be more specific about the problem. It would probably help if there was some text in place of the Content component.

Comment: Please look the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2djy5g-7svg91?file=index.js) which I provided in my question. I think the snippet have static width and height on all screens that is way it's not showing the problem

Comment: What are you getting? Can you take a screenshot and add it? That link you posted has a small screen width so the image is hidden by default, increasing the size shows the image as you're describing. What is the actual problem you're having? It's hard to determine from the current content

Comment: @someone if you have already tried the response I pasted below, I edited it, so please take the new one.

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is, please edit your question to clarify how your code does not match your desired outcome.

Comment: @TylerH,Please look the [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2djy5g-7svg91?file=index.js) which I provided in question. If you see the output you can understand that I can partially locate second image on first one, but that is not dynamic, if you change screen dimensions you can see how that collapse.

Comment: @someone I did look at the code in the question. I have not (and shouldn't need to) look at code that is elsewhere. If the code on your stackblitz is different from what's in your question, you need to update the question's code to match. Please see [mcve]] for more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `transform` and `aspect-ratio` to achieve the result:

```css
.checkoutWrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.left {
  background-color: #baafa0;
  position: relative;
  
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1028/200/300');
  background-size: cover;
}

.phone {
  height: 60%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/2;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
  border-radius: 15%;
}

.right {
  padding-left: calc(15vh + 1rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="checkoutWrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <img class="phone" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/444" />
  </div>
  <div class="right CheckoutProcess">
    <Content>
      <h1>Check Out</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda consectetur ducimus officiis dicta vero distinctio odio sit explicabo illum dolorem quasi facilis repellendus sapiente fuga corporis, iure dolore ad, quis quisquam? Dolorum nostrum, veritatis
        molestiae culpa maiores exercitationem cumque qui harum, unde est ratione doloremque necessitatibus et numquam itaque neque!
      </p>
    </Content>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I edited your [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2djy5g-zbxlpu?file=index.css)

everything that you wrote is correct.

You just forget to add `margin-left: 25%`. no matter which screen you use, it always be partially located on first one. (by center)

Answer (score 1):

With the code below, you have the structure that you want. All you have to do is to play with the `width`, `height`, etc to make exactly what you need.

```css
.checkoutWrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  align-items:center;
}

.checkoutImgs {
  position: relative;
}

img{
  object-fit:cover;
  display:block;
  height:100%;
}

.coverIMGLast {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100vh;
  
}

  
.phone {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80%;
  width:40%;
  top: 10%;
  right: 0;

}

.CheckoutProcess {
  padding: 1rem 2.4rem;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center
}
```

```html
<div class="checkoutWrapper">
  <div class="checkoutImgs">
    <img
      src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1659592516254-c00ca7af3db4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw0fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
      class="coverIMGLast"
    />
    <img
      src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1659808749760-e5baf9c16f10?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxMnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
      class="phone"
    />
  </div>

  <div class="CheckoutProcess">
    Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page
    avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les
    années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour
    réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles,
    mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

check out this code, I created this design for you, may it help...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH6Fm.png)

```css
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .parent {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .left {
        width: 37%;
        background-color: blue;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .right {
        width: 63%;
        background-color: red;
        height: 100vh;

        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .image-container {
        position: absolute;
        height: 60%;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .image {
        height: 500px;
        width: 250px;
        background-color: grey;
        margin-left: 30%;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<body>


    <div class='parent'>
        <div class='left'></div>
        <div class='right'>
            <div>
                <h3>THis is a heading</h3>
                <p>this is a para</p>
                <p>this is a para</p>
                <p>this is a para</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="image-container">
            <div class="image"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the first image as background image, then specify the background-size whichever size you want. Then add the second image inside the `<div>` element.

```css
#bg-img{
  background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/36029/aroni-arsa-children-little.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500');
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50% 100%;
  background-color: #999;
}
#img-inside{
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width:15%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg-img">
  <img id="img-inside" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/36029/aroni-arsa-children-little.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="second-img" />
</div>
```

I just made the left `div` in the snippet

Answer (score 1):

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.checkoutWrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 35% 25% 40%; /* create three columns to fit both images  */
}

.coverIMGLast {
  width: calc(100% - 195px); **/* give that illution of real overlapping */**
  height: 100vh; /* please don't delete this line */
  grid-column: 1 / 3; /* overlapping */
  grid-row: 1;
  object-fit: cover;
}
/* this .phone class should be dynamically  located partially on first image */
.phone {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 380px;
  grid-row: 1; /* setting the images on one track / row */
  grid-column: 1/3; /* overlaping */
  justify-self: end;
  transform: translateY(5vh);
}

.CheckoutProcess {
  padding: 5.8rem 0.5rem 6.4rem; /* Add normal padding to give that effect */
}

.someContent {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .checkoutWrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
  }

  img {
    display: none;
  }

  .CheckoutProcess {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```
<div class="checkoutWrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="coverIMGLast" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/ff0000" class="phone" />
  <div class="CheckoutProcess">
    <div class="someContent">
      <h1>Some heading</h1>
      <p> 
        Some text to go with the paragraph 
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://react-2djy5g-tsheob.stackblitz.io/

As you can see from the above code and link of your edited code.

You just had to make an illusion of the overlapping by using `grid-column` and playing with the template columns to create a book-like feeling.

with :

1. `grid-template-columns: 35% 25% 40%;` /* create three columns to fit both images  */
2. `grid-row: 1;`          /* setting the images on one track / row */
3. `grid-column: 1/3;`    /* overlaping */
4. `justify-self: end;`  /* placing image on the right side of the grid */